# Правильно ли определены первичное и вторичное значения слов?

Tags: значение-слов

1. Корень зуба, ели – первичное значение.
       Корень зла, слова, квадратный - вторичное значение.
2. Игла для инъекций, швейная - первичное значение.
       Игла сосны, морского ежа, адмиралтейская – вторичное значение.
3. Сладкие пирожки - первичное значение.
        Сладкие звуки, улыбки - вторичное значение.
4. Камень на дороге, в почках - первичное значение.
       Камень на сердце - вторичное значение.
5. Ковш экскаватора, для воды - первичное значение.
6. Каша манная - первичное значение.
       Каша бетонная, в голове - вторичное значение.
7. Мурлычет кошка - первичное значение.
       Мурлычет ручей - вторичное значение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ковш экскаватора - вторичное значение.**

Словарь Ушакова:

КОВШ, ковша, муж.
 1. Широкий округлый металлический сосуд с ручкой для зачерпывания жидкостей и питья.
|| Деревянный совок для зачерпывания сыпучих тел.
 2. Металлический сосуд в разных производствах, по форме и назначению похожий на ковш (тех.). Мукомольный ковш. Литейный ковш.
 3. Искусственно замкнутая часть канала или залива, служащая для приема судов в портах (мор.). Ковш Гутуевеского острова (в Ленинградском порту).
 4. Приспособление из высоких палок для ловли тетеревов (охот.).

**КОРЕНЬ зуба - вторичное значение.** Словарь Ожегова:

КО́РЕНЬ, -рн -, мн. -рни, -рней, муж.
1. Подземная часть растения, служащая для укрепления его в почве и всасывания из неё воды и питательных веществ. Главный, боковой, придаточный к. Воздушные корни (у лиан и нек-рых других растенийвысоко над землёй: придаточные корни на надземных побегах). В саду десять корней яблонь (т. е. десять яблонь). Споткнуться о к. (о корень, выступающий из земли). Гнить на корню (также перен.: разлагаясь, гибнуть). Корни пустить (также перен.: прочно обосноваться где-н.; разг.). Под к. подрубить (не оставив пня; также перен.: полностью подорвать, уничтожить). С корнем вырвать (также перен.: уничтожить совсем). От доброго кореня добрая и отрасль (стар. посл.).
2. Внутренняя, находящаяся в теле часть волоса, зуба, ногтя. Покраснеть до корней волос (очень сильно).
3. перен. Начало, источник, истоки чего-н. К. зла. Крепкие корни у кого-чего-н. (давнее происхождение).
4. В языкознании: основная, значимая часть слова, вычленяемая в нём после отделения окончания, приставок и суффиксов.